# localhost/Magento2/setup not working

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

Magento2 is successfully installed on localhost using composer

when i open localhost/magento2/setup.. This is opened

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright Â© 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

if (PHP_SAPI == 'cli') {
    echo "You cannot run this from the command line." . PHP_EOL .
        "Run \"php bin/magento\" instead." . PHP_EOL;
    exit(1);
}
try {
    require __DIR__ . '/../app/bootstrap.php';
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    echo <<<HTML
<div style="font:12px/1.35em arial, helvetica, sans-serif;">
    <div style="margin:0 0 25px 0; border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;">
        <h3 style="margin:0;font-size:1.7em;font-weight:normal;text-transform:none;text-align:left;color:#2f2f2f;">
        Autoload error</h3>
    </div>
    <p>{$e->getMessage()}</p>
</div>
HTML;
    exit(1);
}

// For Setup Wizard we are using our customized error handler
$handler = new \Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler();
set_error_handler([$handler, 'handler']);

\Zend\Mvc\Application::init(require __DIR__ . '/config/application.config.php')->run();
```

Please advise

Edit1  - `app/etc/env.php was missing.`

Edit2 - I have given the following permissions

```
cd /var/www/html/magento2
find var vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type f -exec chmod u+w {} \;
find var vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type d -exec chmod u+w {} \;
cd /var/www && sudo chown -R www-data:www-data .
chmod u+x bin/magento
```

Comment: permissions could be an issue.

Comment: which file ?? though i ran this                 above commands (edit2)

Comment: does Apache have mod-php ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12142172/apache-shows-php-code-instead-of-executing